# passing AsyncPipe as a function parameter

Tags: angular, asynchronous, pipe

am having the following

```
<button (click)="showResult( (listItem.SiteName|async)?.$value )"> 
    {{(listItem.SiteName|async)?.$value}}
</button>
```

and am getting error when trying to pass the AsyncPipe as a parameter, is there any way to pass the value rather than to pass the observable or promise and unwrap it inside the function ?

Comment: instead of using async (which does the subscription for you) You can instead subscribe in your component as where you end up with a "normal" JS Object/Array, which you then can pass to in your `showResult` function.